# php function problem

Tags: php, function

OK, one more problem and then I think my function will work.

Right now,  my second function is just reporting the character length back next to the string like so:

```
    string(20) "testing testing nice"
```

is there anyway to change the format of that return? And what do I need to change to get the WORD count too?

Is it even possible to make the format look like this:

```
   string word count: 3 character count: 20 "testing testing nice"
```

thanks

file1.php

```
    <?php
    require('myfunctions.php');
    if($_POST) {
    $result = phptest($_POST['input']);
    if ($result === false) {
    echo 'No mean words were found.';
    } else {
    var_dump($result);
    }
    }
    ?>

    <?php
    echo "<br/> Sum function: ".sum(1,2,3,4)."<br/>";
    echo "Average function: ".average(1,2,3,4)."<br/>";
    ?>

    <form action="" method="post">
    <input name="input" type="text" size="20" maxlength="20" />
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
```

myfunctions.php

```
    <?php
    function sum() {
    return array_sum(func_get_args());
    }

    function average() {
    $args = func_num_args();

    if ($args == 0) {
    return 0;
    }

    return array_sum(func_get_args()) / $args;
    }  
    ?>

    <?php
    function phptest($input) {
    $search = array('ugly', 'rude');
    $replace = array('nice', 'sweet');
    $output = str_ireplace($search, $replace, $input, $replace_count);
    if ($replace_count === 0) {
    return false;
    } else {
    return $output;
    }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: I don't see any correlation between the question and the code snippet

Comment: Do you use `var_dump` somewhere? That is for debugging and no, you can't change that format. But you can make your own output.

Comment: looks like he's just `var_dump`ing the returned value and wants to reformat what var_dump gives

Comment: @ yi_H To clarify, my function is being used to replace words and then the completed string (with replaced words) should be returned with the word count. Does that help any?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [str_word_count](http://php.net/str_word_count) function to count words in a string.

```
function str_info($string) {
  $words = str_word_count($string);
  $chars = strlen($string); //Consideer using mb_strlen if you're using Unicode
  return 'string word count: '. $words .' character count: '. $chars .' '. $string;
}
```

Comment: +1 I wasn't aware of the str_word_count() function. Very handy!